# If $f(x) = x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ and $f(y)\leq f(x)$ for all $x$, then there is a number $b>y$ such that $f(b)>f(y)$

Tags: calculus, continuity, proof-explanation

Chapter 7 of Spivak's Calculus 3rd edition contains what he calls "Three Hard Theorems" and some of their consequences. The given proofs are clear, but one contains a little detail which bothers me. (Note that all "numbers" are real numbers.)

> **Theorem 11:**
> Consider the equation $$(*)\quad x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=c,$$ and suppose $n$ is even. Then there is a number $m$ such that $(*)$ has a solution for $c\geq m$ an has no solution for $c<m$.
>
> **Proof:** Let $f(x) = x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$. According to Theorem 10 there is a number $y$ such that $f(y)\leq f(x)$ for all x. Let $m=f(y)$. If $c<m$, then the equation $(*)$ obviously has no solution, since the left side always has a value $\geq m$. If $c=m$, then $(*)$ has $y$ as a solution. Finally, suppose $c>m$. *Let $b$ be a number such that $b>y$ and $f(b)>c$.* Then $f(y)=m<c<f(b).$ Consequently, by Theorem 4 (Intermediate Value Theorem), there is some number $x$ in $[y,b]$ such that $f(x)=c$, so $x$ is a solution of $(*)$.

Maybe I'm missing something he has mentioned previously in an earlier chapter or problem, but how do I know that there exists a number $b$ such that $b>y$ and $f(b)>c$?

I worked out a proof, analogous to the first part of the proof of Theorem 9 of this chapter, that a number b exists if $f(y)<1$:

Let $M=max(1, \frac{n|a_{n-1}|}{1-f(y)}, \cdots, \frac{n|a_{0}|}{1-f(y)} )$. Then for all $x$ with $|x|>M$ we have $$f(y)<1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+ \cdots  +\frac{a_{0}}{x^n},$$
so $$f(y)\leq f(y)x^n<\left(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+ \cdots  +\frac{a_{0}}{x^n}\right)x^n=f(x).$$

Thus, choose $b>M$.

Unfortunately I can't go any further than that. (The complete proof of Theorem 9 can be found on this site. I can include more details, if needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, there is some $b\in(y,\infty)$ such that $f(b)>c$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I missed that completely.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.